# Test driven development using ARM vendors HAL

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd

I'm writing a driver for a sensor in C using test driven development approach. Driver will be used in project utilizing STM32F415 ARM processor. Project is generated using CubeMX software which among other things also generates vendor specific hardware abstraction layer files for various peripherals. I am to use files generated for SPI communication protocol, *stm32f4xx_hal_spi.h* and corresponding source file, in my sensor driver.

My goal is to create a mock for SPI interface and then test drive my sensor driver. I would also like to abstract SPI HAL from my driver code as much as possible. Reason for this is that same driver will also have to support I2C protocol so ideally they would be easily swappable. This is also the reason I would like to avoid copying SPI HAL files directly into my sensor driver.

My initial approach was to create a separate header file, `spi_interface.h` and use it to re-declare functions I will need from `stm32f4xx_hal_spi.h`. Then I would generate a mock from this header file. This would allow me to test drive the rest of driver interface.

However, SPI HAL functions are more complex than I initially thought. This is an example of one:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

My question is related to *SPI_HandleTypeDef* struct that the SPI HAL functions use as parameter:

```
typedef struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef
{
  SPI_TypeDef                *Instance;    /* SPI registers base address */

  SPI_InitTypeDef            Init;         /* SPI communication parameters */

  uint8_t                    *pTxBuffPtr;  /* Pointer to SPI Tx transfer Buffer */

  uint16_t                   TxXferSize;   /* SPI Tx Transfer size */

  __IO uint16_t              TxXferCount;  /* SPI Tx Transfer Counter */

  uint8_t                    *pRxBuffPtr;  /* Pointer to SPI Rx transfer Buffer */

  uint16_t                   RxXferSize;   /* SPI Rx Transfer size */

  __IO uint16_t              RxXferCount;  /* SPI Rx Transfer Counter */

  void                       (*RxISR)(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi); /* function pointer on Rx ISR */

  void                       (*TxISR)(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi); /* function pointer on Tx ISR */

  DMA_HandleTypeDef          *hdmatx;      /* SPI Tx DMA Handle parameters   */

  DMA_HandleTypeDef          *hdmarx;      /* SPI Rx DMA Handle parameters   */

  HAL_LockTypeDef            Lock;         /* Locking object                 */

  __IO HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef  State;        /* SPI communication state */

  __IO uint32_t              ErrorCode;    /* SPI Error code */

}SPI_HandleTypeDef;
```

It is comprised of multiple other structs which made me think hard about the right approach here. Is there a well established way of handling structs when mocking vendor HAL interface? Do I copy all the needed `struct` definitions to my `spi_interface.h`? Is my initial plan valid in this situation?

Comment: Bloatware HAL to write another unnecessary abstraction level. IMO idea 100% wrong. uC  programming requires completely different approach. If you want to write your own abstraction layer programme the uC on the hardware (register) level

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google search for 'SPI bit bash' or 'SPI bit bang' and then port it across to the STM32.  The only porting you should really be doing is swapping out the GPIO layer of the code you're porting to the STM.  So look for code that abstracts this part away and makes it easy for you to swap this part out. I guess you could try [this driver](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/tools/appnotes/4184/4184_spi.c) from Maxim.  Just port the `spiReadReg ()` and `spiWriteReg()` functions.

As a start you would swap something like `SPI_CS = 1;` with something like `GPIO_SetBits(YOUR_SPI_PORT, YOUR_GPIO_CS_PIN);`.

With SPI, it does not matter how slowly you operate the bus.  You can go as slow as you like and work your way up in speed until you notice errors.

For I2C, I have successfully ported [this driver](https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en560799) from Microchip across to the STM32F and made it work with an I2C-based battery balancer/monitor from TI.  If the code you're working with is simple enough, it should be an easy and relatively painless, if not fun job.